# How to parse such type of JSON data for the dynamic key

Tags: android, json

```
{"Freedom Plan 4900":
    {
    "sale_price1":["$10.00","$20.00","$25.00","$50.00","$100.00"],
    "loc_rate1":["India (2.0&cent; per min)"],
    "net_minutes1":["500","1,000","1,250","2,500","5,000"],
    "loc_rate":["India - Mobile (1.5&cent; per min)"],
    "net_minutes":["666","1,333","1,666","3,433","6,866"]
    },

"Super Offer Plan":
    {
    "sale_price1":["$10.00"],
    "loc_rate1":["India (1.5&cent; per min)"],
    "net_minutes1":["667"],
    "loc_rate":["India - Mobile (1.0&cent; per min)"],
    "net_minutes":["1,000"]
    }
```

}

i want to parse this json string

Comment: I am completed this   how to do

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like GSON:

http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Create classes to hold the data (e.g. `PhonePlan` etc) and let GSON parse the JSON string.

```
PhonePlan plan = gson.fromJson(json, PhonePlan.class);
```

Comment: how will gson be able to parse the dynamic key?